# React.js using array.prototype.map on props returns empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm dipping my toes into the world of React, and have come across an issue when trying to transform the value of props into a JSX element using array.prototype.map() (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

below is a React Component which renders the navigation bar of my page:-

```
class NavBar extends React.Component
{
   buttons = this.props.options.map(option => {return <li id={option['option']}>{option['option']}</li>});

   render()
   {
      return (
         <nav>
            {this.buttons}
         </nav>
      );
   }
}
```

This component is called in a parent component as so:-

```
<NavBar options={this.state.options}/>
```

where:-

```
this.state = { 
   options: [
             {'option': 'Button One', 'active': false},
             {'option': 'Button Two', 'active': true},
             {'option': 'Button Three', 'active': false}
            ]
}
```

The problem is that when I call this.buttons in the NavBar component, it returns an empty array. I did a bit of debugging and found that when the following code is added to the render function:-

```
<p>{JSON.stringify(this.props.options)}</p>
```

Then the value outputted in the p tag pulls through as expected, meaning that this.props is pulling through correctly. I also found that it works correctly when set up as a functional component (i.e. without a class and removing 'this.' before each occurrence of 'props').

Has anybody seen this error before, and if so, do you know what's causing it?

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: I don't see there `constructor(props) { super(props); }` and also why don't you use functional components?

Comment: You need to put the .map inside the render method.

Comment: @DominikMatis I did consider using a functional component for this case, however given that the NavBar component should pass information back up to its parent component, a class component is required here.

Comment: @GuyIncognito I just gave that a go and it resolved the issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As explained by @GuyIncognito, I was able to resolve the issue by moving the buttons variable into the render() method.

Thanks!